# Use Last Used DevExpress Style

Tags: c#, coding-style, settings, devexpress

I'm looking to have a setting feature or something of the sort that will by default use the last selected style.

Example:  Form has the new application style gallery in the ribbon.  When the user selects the style they want, and close out the application it will stay.  So when they open it up the next time it will use the style selected when last opened.

I have absolutely no idea on how to go about doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have published an example showing how this can be done at:

[How to save a skin name applied  to an application to be able to apply it at the next application run?](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/CodeCentral/ViewExample.aspx?exampleId=E2897)